# jsPlumb and Dynamic Windows on Initialization

Tags: css, jsplumb

I'm trying to initialize jsPlumb with a variable number of starting windows, depending on the case. Because the windows must be absolutely positioned, they overlap one another on initialization and I can't set the css ahead of time to space them out properly. This is my view:

```
<div class="flowchart-demo" id="tree">
        @foreach (var level0 in Model.Level0)
        {
            <div class="window" id="@level0.Id"><strong>@level0.FirstName @level0.LastName</strong><span class="ep"></span></div>
        }
        <div class="break"></div>
        @foreach (var level1 in Model.Level1)
        {
            <div class="window" id="@level1.Id"><strong>@level1.FirstName @level1.LastName</strong><span class="ep"></span></div>
        }
        <div class="break"></div>
        @foreach (var level2 in Model.Level2)
        {
            <div class="window" id="@level2.Id"><strong>@level2.FirstName @level2.LastName</strong><span class="ep"></span></div>
        }
    </div>
```

Does anyone have experience with jsPlumb to know how to use it for dynamic initialization?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am using jquery animate to reposition the absolute elements:

```
$("div.window").each(function(i, elem) {
    var pos = i * 300;
    $(this).animate({ left: pos + "px" });
});
```